# Data table columns sort laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, datatables-1.10

This is my table [image]

Controller code

```
public function index(Datatables $datatables,Request $request)
{
    $model=Customer::whereIn('group_id',[1,4]);
    return $datatables->eloquent($model)->editColumn('name',function($customer){

      return $customer->name.' '.$customer->last_name;
      })->editColumn('type',function($customer){

            return $customer->customergroup?$customer->customergroup->customer_group:'';

          })->editColumn('member_since',function($customer){

           return $customer->created_at->format('d-m-Y');

          })->editColumn('booking_made',function($customer){

          return $customer->bookings?$customer->bookings->count():0;

          })->editColumn('status',function($customer){

      return '<span class="label label-sm  '.($customer->status?"label-green-jungle":"btn red").'">'.($customer->status?"Active":"Inactive").'</span>';

  })->rawColumns(['status'])->make(true);
}
```

Data table script code

```
$(function () {
table= $('#customer-table').DataTable({   

    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    bFilter: false,
    ajax:"{{route('admin.customer.index') }}",
    columns: [                   
 {data: 'id',name:'id'},
 {data: 'name',name:'name'},
 {data: 'type',name:'group_id'},
 {data: 'member_since',name:'created_at'},
 {data: 'booking_made',name:'booking_made'},    
 {data: 'status',name:'status'},
 {data: 'view',searchable:false},      

 ],    
 "order": [[ 0,'desc' ]],
 columnDefs: [{
      targets: [6,8],
      orderable: false
   }]            
 });
});
```

From the table(image) You can see a column `Bookings Made` it is the count of total booking by each customer. So the problem is that how can i sort the table according to count.I can sort `customer name`,and `status`.

Comment: what is the result if you remove `columnDefs` in script code?

Comment: It returns this error `Exception Message:↵↵SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'booking_made' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from customer  where  group_id in (1, 4) and customer.deleted_at is null order by booking_made desc limit 25 offset 0)`